# Запуск selenium-server с доступом только с локалхоста

Tags: сеть

Добрый день. Потребовалось организовать CI на простом VPS. Selenium автоматом стартует на айпи :: (аналог 0.0.0.0 на IPv4) и доступен для всего мира, что требуется закрыть, причем желательно не через iptables, а средствами самого selenium, хочется написать один раз скрипт и навсегда забыть про его содержимое. Ключ `-host`, к сожалению, не помог. Кто-нибудь сталкивался/знает, как это организовать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21677988/815386>  Please mark as correct one of the answers that has -host 192.168.1.100 it is now available on selenium >= 2.40.0 –  elgalu Mar 6 at 18:52 в общем версию проверьте, говорят, что  --host работает а ещё мб ваша vps поддерживает docker.io ? сделайте док, просто с selenium :)

Comment: @eicto, у меня 2.42.2, -host, насколько понял, используется только в системе из нескольких серверов. docker.io посмотрю.

Comment: В результате перестал париться и написал пару строчек в iptables.